# Creating msg and srv tutorial

Tags: ros, message-generation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv)

> There's one more step, though. We need
> to make sure that the msg files are
> turned into source code for C++,
> Python, and other languages:
>
> Open package.xml, and make sure these three lines are in it and uncommented:

```
<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <run_depend>message_generation</run_depend>
  <run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>
```

> Note that at build time, we need
> "message_generation", while at
> runtime, we only need
> "message_runtime".

My question is:
It says that **while at runtime, we only need "message_runtime".** , then why it put the message generation in run_depend (look at the three lines)?

In addition, can you please explain what are **message_generation, message_runtime** , and all these things we put in the middle of build_depend ,run_depend, and other tags are?
noob questions

Lastly....
I noticed that in the tutorial:
while in creating msg, it mentions to call generate_message function and to make sure we export message_runtime dependecy. In creating srv, it doesn't mention to do so.
**Is it not required for creating a srv? Why?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/241540/creating-msg-and-srv-tutorial/) by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 582 on 2016-08-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1 I think you can remove the message_generation in run_depend. Please have a look at here (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) It is just :

`<build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>`

`<run_depend>message_runtime</run_depend>`

2 (Despite its name, message_generation works for both msg and srv.) I think its the same for message_runtime.

---

Originally posted by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) with karma: 80 on 2016-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-14**:
Yah I know message_generation works for both msg and srv. What I means is that : If I create a srv (assuming I haven't created anything before), do I need call generate_message function and make sure exporet message_runtime dependecy as well?

**Comment by [ghkraju](https://answers.ros.org/users/27712/ghkraju/) on 2016-08-15**:
Yes, You need them while catkin_make otherwise you will get a compilation error for the source file where you linked the respective service since it doesn't what that service is......